# Is there any way to print something without using any strings or numbers in Python?

Tags: python, string, numbers

Is there any way to print something, anything (like say `Hello World!`), that ***does not use*** `"` or `'` or a number?

This is for a current [DMOJ](https://dmoj.ca) problem that I am doing. Here is the problem: [Too Simple](https://dmoj.ca/problem/toosimple).

Now, one may go, "Oh. Okay. I can just do something like

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://Too-Simple-Site--ariari.repl.co/index.html')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

hello = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')

for char in hello: 
  print (char, end='')
```

and solve this. However, the catch is that there are ***only built-in modules allowed***. So, how would I go about doing this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186541/discussion-on-question-by-arihan-sharma-sir-john-a-mac-is-there-any-way-to-pri).

Answer (score 1):

(Being someone who has solved this problem)

This problem is actually surprisingly straightforward, and there are really only three things that you have to know:

1. `True` when cast to an integer has a value of `1`
2. You can use the `chr` function to convert a char code (which is an Integer) into a character
3. You don't have to write the code by hand yourself, you can always write a program to generate code.

Obviously basic knowledge about strings (what character codes are, etc.) will also be required.

Good luck!

Edit: Once you know those things, piecing together a solution shouldn't be too difficult